# How can I make www.mywebsite.com/blog?

Tags: wordpress, apache, google-app-engine, ubuntu, blogs

I have my website(HTML files) in a google cloud instance.
(ex: www.mywbsite.com)

To start the blog, installed Wordpress using google cloud one-click installation at another instance, which is working fine, but to access it, I use an Ip address (different from the main website).

So, on one hand, I have the site, and at another have I have the Blog IP.

How can I merge these two things to achieve the following result?
To this:
www.mywebsite.com/blog (same instance or some link to the second)

From this:
www.mywbsite.com (instance 1) + WP Blog IP (instance 2)

If you can point me some links/tutorials to better understand and solve this, I would be appreciated.

Have to tell you I am a very inexperienced tech guy, but eagerly trying to learn.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use like subdirectory, it has to be in your instance-1 **or** you can use `.htaccess` and redirect to your instance-2.

However, if you use like this, you can't do what you want because Apache will rewrite address again and it will see `www.instance-2.com`.

I hope, it will answer your question; otherwise, let me know. I will update the answer.

#### Edit 1 - Add links

- [Usage of .htaccess for redirect](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file)
- [Redirect and Rewrite URLs with .htaccess](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Wordpress in a subdirectory instead of using cloud launcher and having it on another server. It's really easy to install WordPress manually. [This](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress) is my favorite guide for any Debian based situation, not just rpi. Also [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) is the guide on the WordPress Codex. Just install it to the /blog subdirectory.